# Why does rustc allow me to leak a private type?

Tags: rust

I have made a minimal example. In `lib.rs`:

```
mod sealed {
    pub enum Choice {
        A,
        B,
    }
}

pub fn print_choice(choice: sealed::Choice) {
    match choice {
        sealed::Choice::A => println!("Choice A"),
        sealed::Choice::B => println!("Choice B"),
    }
}
```

I think: The enum `Choice` is public. However, it's in a private mod, and cannot be reached from outside of the crate. Therefore the function `print_choice` is not callable at all.

What is wrong with my thinking?

Comment: The [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/visibility-and-privacy.html) has some use cases for this.

Comment: I don't think you're using "de facto" right. A de facto private type is one that is *actually* private, as you might contrast with one that is *nominally* private (but actually public in some sense). If you can leak it, it can't be considered private *de facto*, right? I am removing the phrase from the title but if you feel this is important I encourage you to clarify in the question what you mean.

Answer (score 7):

> What is wrong with my thinking?

You could have something like

```rust
pub use sealed::Choice;
```

at the toplevel. That is a common way to split up the implementation while providing a simple single-module interface to external users.

Or even just an other function returning an instance of `Choice`. Since it's `pub`, it's not considered a private type.

If you change `pub enum` to `pub(crate) enum` (meaning you state that the enum *can not* be made visible outside the crate) then the compilation will fail.

Answer (score 6):

An important thing to understand is that *`Choice` is not private*. It is inside a private module, and thus *unnamable*, but it is public.

The only thing the module's privacy affects is that you cannot access the enum *via this path*. You can do any other thing with it, e.g. accessing it via other path it is reexported into:

```rust
mod sealed {
    pub enum Choice {
        A,
        B,
    }
}
pub use sealed::Choice;

// In other module
crate::Choice::A;
```

Or manipulate it with generics and traits, for example:

```rust
mod sealed {
    pub enum Choice {
        A,
        B,
    }
    impl Default for Choice {
        fn default() -> Self { Self::A }
    }
}

pub fn print_choice(choice: sealed::Choice) { ... }

// In other module
crate::print_choice(Default::default());
```

```rust
mod sealed {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub enum Choice {
        A,
        B,
    }
}

pub fn print_choice(choice: sealed::Choice) { crate::print(choice) }

// In other module
pub fn print<T: Debug>(v: T) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

This private type seems to leak, but you don't have full control over it.

You cannot build such a private `Choice`, but another public function can provide you with it.

```rust
mod outer {

    mod sealed {
        pub enum Choice {
            A,
            B,
        }
    }

    pub fn print_choice(choice: sealed::Choice) {
        match choice {
            sealed::Choice::A => println!("Choice A"),
            sealed::Choice::B => println!("Choice B"),
        }
    }

    pub fn make_choice(n: u32) -> sealed::Choice {
        if n % 2 == 0 {
            sealed::Choice::A
        } else {
            sealed::Choice::B
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // let ch = outer::sealed::Choice::A; // error: module `sealed` is private
    let ch = outer::make_choice(2);
    outer::print_choice(ch);
}
```